# Can spaCy's dependency parser give grammatically incorrect parse trees?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am trying to conceptualize a rule-based grammar checker that analyzes sentences run through a dependency parser.

If I gave spaCy's dependency parser a grammatically incorrect sentence on purpose (for example "I football play"), it seems to always try to generate a grammatically correct parse tree.

Is my idea inherently flawed?

I used spaCy's dependency parser and inputted incorrect sentences on purpose and saw that spaCy attempts to make the sentence follow correct grammar.